# i can't access to WEB-INF/file.jsp even with using request dispatcher i got error 404

Tags: java, jsp, web-inf

[image]

I can't access to `WEB-INF/test.jsp` even with using request dispatcher and    froward method from a 'servlet' , i get error `404` and when i try to access to `http://localhost:8080/app/test.jsp` ,where `"/app"` is the project name ,

Please help me , i don't know where is the problem

Comment: plz  click on "enter image description here" to see my problem

Answer (score 0):

JSP pages inside WEB-INF can not be accessed by URL. So `http://localhost:8080/app/test.js` would never work.

In your Servlet just add "/" before WEB-INF. So it should be:

```
"/WEB-INF/test.jsp"
```